# What file system operations are required when loading a class from a jars only classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, classloader

I'm working on a large application that is built upon a platform that currently uses file system classpath locations for most of the classpath entries when being run. This causes a lot of `File.exists()` invocations during startup classloading since every entry in the classpath must be checked for existence of the class until the first match is found.

CPU Sampling has shown that about 70% of startup time is spend for these lookups on a developer machine with a SSD.

And whats more important is that adding a single file system classpath entry in the middle of the classpath may cause an additional linear overhead to classloading because of this.

The idea we have is that we package the current file system classpath locations into jars and replace the file system classpath entries with those jars.

Now before trying that out I wanted to make sure that there will be actually less file system operations required when loading a class from a class path that contains jars only compared to a classpath that contains a lot of file system locations. The problem is that I got stuck in class `java.util.zip.ZipFile` that is used during classloading from a jar, because it uses native code (Oracle JDK 1.8.0_111)

So the actual question is:

**Does locating a specific zip entry in a `java.util.zip.ZipFile` always require file system operations, even if the zip file was accessed before?**

Comment: Can you influence the behavior of this framework at all? I am wondering if the right approach would be fixing that part of the equation?!

Comment: @GhostCat yes in this case, because it only affects the main class that is being used to start the platform instance which dynamically assembles the classpath being used.

Comment: Not sure if I understand; maybe I rephrase my question: wouldn't be the better option to fix the way this framework deals with the classpath? You know, when the JVM starts, the classpath is no longer "dynamic"; so couldn't you do some "caching" there (for example reading the **names** of all classes and their locations) into memory first; and make such decisions based on that content? Instead of asking the file system 100 times for the same question?

Comment: @GhostCat "when the JVM starts, the classpath is no longer "dynamic"" - as far as I understand the mechanisms of the platform this task seems to be much like the one I have in mind because the platform startup has to be changed in both cases. But for your case I would need to use a classloaded that does actually do this kind of caching. This may cause other problems because I don't know that much about classloading mechanism, security related things there and so on.

Comment: You should avoid filesystem directories in the CLASSPATH, and only use JAR files. I was telling colleagues this in 1998.

Comment: @EJP obviously you did not reach enough people ;)

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I didn't reach *anybody* at the time ... and the application was distributed on CD-ROM. Never seen such appalling load times.